# How can I perform a map-like function but still be able to use active record methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I have the following where I use map:

```
last_activities = report.deals.map do |deal|
  deal.activities.last
end
```

I then want to be able to use 'where' on 'last_activities' but I can't do that because last_activities is an array.  What I would like to do, but can't, is:

```
fun_activities = last_activities.where(:type => "fun")
```

How can I accomplish this in rails?

Update:

Report has_many deals
Deal belongs_to report
Deal has_many activities
Activity belongs_to deal

Comment: What are the relations between Reports, Deals and Activities?

Comment: whats wrong with reject and select? why do you need a SQL statement for such a simple case?

Comment: I don't need a SQL statement; just trying to illustrate what I want to achieve.  You would suggest reject and select?

Comment: You don't want the ones that are "fun" if the last one is of another type. Or you do want the last one of type fun on each?

Comment: Only looking at the last activities associated with a deal, and from them, selecting the ones of type fun.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1) go on with arrays. that would be, selecting the fun activities with select:
    fun_activities = last_activities.select { |a| a.type == "fun"}

2) define a SQL statement that selects the activities you want directly or trying to achieve the same using ActiveRecord queries - this would have the advantage of better performance or not loading everything into an array.

Answer (score 0):

If they are few you can do map and select as said in comments

```
all_last_activities = report.deals.map do |deal|
  deal.activities.last
end

fun_last_activities = all_last_activities.select do |act|
  act.type == "fun"
end
```

If there are a lot of records you better do it with a query like

```
all_last_activities_ids = report.deals.map do |deal|
  deal.activities.last.id
end

Activity.where(type: "fun").find(all_last_activities_ids)
```

Also you should get `all_last_activities_ids` from a query but I have no time to find out how to do it right now. But a group clause should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with an AR/SQL query, here's how to do it:

```
Activity.joins(:deal).where(['deals.report_id = ? and activities.id in (select max(id) from activities group by deal_id)'], report.id)
```

This will allow chaining conditions like you wanted to in the original question.
For simplicity and readability however, you might want to prefer the select/reject approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) it's easy to express this in ruby without writing raw SQL queries:

```
max_ids_rel = Activity.group{deal_id}.select{max(id)}

Activity.joins{deal}.where{(deal.report_id == my{report.id}) && id.in(max_ids_rel)}
```

This should generate a subselect similar to the suggestion by HargrimmTheBleak. A join with a generated table would also be possible, but that would require a few more grouping statements and isn't necessary as a good query analyzer should be able to turn this into a join anyway.